# Accessing parent class property set by child class

Tags: java, groovy

I'm trying to access a property from a method in a parent class where that property is initialized in a child class like so:

```
abstract class Parent {
    String description
    String name

    def printDescription() {
        println "description: ${description}"
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    String description = "child description"
}

Child child = new Child(name: 'Mark')
child.printDescription()                       // prints "description: null"
```

When the method is executed however, the `description` property is `null`. I need to pass the child's `description` back up to the parent constructor. What is the best way to do that while maintaining grails' auto-generated map constructors? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Adding an empty constructor does actually work for what I'm looking for. The constructor is still called when using grails dynamic map constructor, e.g. `Child child = new Child(name: 'Mark')`.

```
Child() {
    this.description = "child description"
}
```

Comment: Don't know about grails, but I guess you shouldn't declare new description and initialize it in constructor instead

Comment: Yep, I guess I shouldn't be surprised but that actually works in grails without any further work necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the description variable of the child class but trying to access the description variable of the parent class, which was never set.

Comment: Thanks, I just wasn't sure the best way to pass the description value to the parent via grails dynamic constructors, but it's a lot easier than I thought :)

Comment: Can you show those of us who don't know how it's done?